# Would Recording Jmeter script from Chrome enumerator very similar to selected mobile device?

Tags: mobile, jmeter, performance-testing

In Chrome DevTools, I have selected Iphone 12 pro and recorded Jemter script(using blazemeter extension), would this be very similar to performing actions in Iphone 12 pro?[[image: Chrome browser]]

Opening .jmx file does show as if it is Iphone but I just want to know if it is the similar processing capacity as an iphone selected.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the website you're testing, normally they identify the user device/operating system/browser version from [User-Agent header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) so it should be sufficient.

In case you want the complete confidence you can record your test from the iphone directly using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html). You will need to:

1. Import JMeter's certificate to your iphone. The file is called `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` and it's being generated in the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation when you start HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder
2. [Enable full trust](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204477) for the JMeter's certificate
3. Configure iphone to use JMeter as the proxy

Or if you prefer to stay with BlazeMeter stack you can use their Proxy Recorder service, it simplifies the above steps and has nice feature of exporting recorded tests in SmartJMX mode with automatic detection and correlation of dynamic parameters. See [Configure Apple Devices for Proxy Recording](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354690550545-Configure-Apple-Devices-for-Proxy-Recording) for more details.

Comment: Hey,  I Tried the second option(recording from mobile) but coz of proxies its hard, anyway, thanks for the info.

Comment: I believe, it is very close as "User-agent" is showing the device its picking.